# baqend, issue with saving data in database

Tags: angular, typescript, baqend

> Hello,
>   I have an issue with saving data in my database, I can’t find
>   the problem. The `QueryBuilder` for `And-, Or- and OrAnd-Select` are
>   the same. . I wrote the`QueryBuilder` in code consecutively for `And-select`, `Or-select` and `OrAnd-Select` in this exact order.
>    Saving data in `NosqlDb` works only for `And- and OR-select`.
>
> But `OrAnd-select` fails to save. In the picture shown,
>   you can see that the data in database doesn’t save. Data in database
>   `User_DataDb` saves successfully. 
>   I would appreciate any help!
>
> Thank you in advance.
>
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvPOP.png)
>
> I get this error:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Current operation has not been finished.
withLock@http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:21238:31 [angular]
_save@http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:11260:12 [angular]
update@http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:11097:12 [angular]
update@http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:12956:14 [angular]
ac_main</NoSqlComponent.prototype.submit/promise</</<@http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:29457:21 [angular]
onInvoke@http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:30326:28 [angular]
polyfills_lib</</</Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4133:24 [angular => angular]
scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4720:52 [angular]
onInvokeTask@http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:30317:28 [angular]
polyfills_lib</</</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4373:17 [angular]
polyfills_lib</</</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4173:28 [<root> => angular]
drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4553:25 [<root>]
ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4431:25 [<root>]
```

> My code

```
/////////////// queryBuilder for And-Select
        var queryBuilderAnd = db.NoSqlDB.find();
        var techniques = queryBuilderAnd
            .in('techniques', this.arrStrTchn);
        var functional = queryBuilderAnd
            .in('functional', this.arrStrFn);
        var nonFunctional = queryBuilderAnd
            .in('nonFunctional', this.arrStrNFn);
        var promiseAnd = queryBuilderAnd.and(techniques, functional, nonFunctional)
            .resultList()
            .then((nosqlDbAnd) => {
                console.log(nosqlDbAnd);

                this.nosqlDbsAnd = nosqlDbAnd;
                console.log("this.nosqlDbsAnd ", this.nosqlDbsAnd);

                this.nosqlDbsAnd.forEach(
                    (and) => {
                        console.log("and: " + and.id);
                        db.NoSqlDB.find()
                            .equal('id', and.id)
                            .resultList((result) => {
                                result.forEach((todo) => {
                                    and.select_and = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.andselected));
                                    if (and.users_and === null) {
                                        and.users_and = new Set();
                                    }
                                    and.users_and.add(db.User.me);
                                    return and.update();
                                });
                            });
     new db.User_DataDb(
         {
          functional_select: this.functionalCatObj, nonfunctional_select: this.nfunctionalCatObj,
          techniques_select: this.techniquesCatObj, functional_unselect: this.functionalUnsCatObj,
          nonfunctional_unselect: this.nfunctionalCatObj, techniques_unselect: this.techniquesUnsCatObj,
          ref_NosqlDbAnd: [and.id]

           }).insert()
                    .then((todo1) => {
                     console.log("todo1.id: ", todo1.id);
                     db.User_DataDb.find()
                          .where({
                                'ref_NosqlDbAnd': and.id,
                                'id': todo1.id
                            })
                            .resultList((result) => {
                                result.forEach(
                                    (todo2) => {
                                        if (todo2.user_and === null) {
                                            todo2.user_and = new Set();
                                        }

                                        todo2.user_and.add(db.User.me);
                                        return todo2.save({ refresh: true });
                                    });
                            });
                    });
            });
      });    

/////////////// queryBuilder for OR-Select
        var queryBuilderOr = db.NoSqlDB.find();
        var techniques = queryBuilderOr
            .in('techniques', this.arrStrTchn);
        var functional = queryBuilderOr
            .in('functional', this.arrStrFn);
        var nonFunctional = queryBuilderOr
            .in('nonFunctional', this.arrStrNFn);
        var promiseOr = queryBuilderOr.or(techniques, functional, nonFunctional)
            .resultList()
            .then((nosqlDbOr) => {
                console.log(nosqlDbOr);

                this.nosqlDbsOr = nosqlDbOr;
                console.log("this.nosqlDbsOr ", this.nosqlDbsOr);

                this.nosqlDbsOr.forEach(
                    (or) => {

                        db.NoSqlDB.find()
                            .equal('id', or.id)
                            .resultList((result) => {
                                result.forEach((todo) => {
                                    or.select_or = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.orselected));
                                    if (or.users_or === null) {
                                        or.users_or = new Set();
                                    }
                                    or.users_or.add(db.User.me);

                                    return or.update();
                                });
                            });
     new db.User_DataDb(
         {
          functional_select: this.functionalCatObj, nonfunctional_select: this.nfunctionalCatObj,
          techniques_select: this.techniquesCatObj, functional_unselect: this.functionalUnsCatObj,
          nonfunctional_unselect: this.nfunctionalCatObj, techniques_unselect: this.techniquesUnsCatObj,
          ref_NosqlDbOr: [or.id]

           }).insert()
                    .then((todo1) => {
                     console.log("todo1.id: ", todo1.id);
                     db.User_DataDb.find()
                          .where({
                                'ref_NosqlDbOr': or.id,
                                'id': todo1.id
                            })
                            .resultList((result) => {
                                result.forEach(
                                    (todo2) => {
                                        if (todo2.user_or === null) {
                                            todo2.user_or = new Set();
                                        }

                                        todo2.user_or.add(db.User.me);
                                        return todo2.save({ refresh: true });
                                    });
                            });
                    });
            });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem here is, that you try modifying an object wich you are saving at the same time.
You should ensure that you modify and save the same object only once a time.

In addition, you should not load already loaded objects:

```
var promiseOr = queryBuilderOr.or(techniques, functional, nonFunctional)
    .resultList()
    .then((nosqlDbOr) => {
        console.log(nosqlDbOr);
        this.nosqlDbsOr = nosqlDbOr;
        console.log("this.nosqlDbsOr ", this.nosqlDbsOr);

        this.nosqlDbsOr.forEach((or) => {
            //you do not need a db.NoSqlDB.find() here the object is already loaded

            if (and.users_or === null) {
                and.users_or = new Set();
            }
            or.users_or.add(db.User.me);

            //You are selecting the same object in the different queries multiple times. 
            //Therfore do not update the objects in each of the resultList() callbacks
            return or.update();
        });
    });
```